# How to use a stored procedure in ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables; I write a stored procedure in ADO.NET Entity Framework.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetDepartmanData]
(@departman nvarchar(50))
BEGIN
  SELECT  
    d.ID, d.Name as DepartmanName,  
    sb.Salary, sb.email,
    sp.Name, sp.SurName, sp.Phone, sp.Married, sp.Address
  FROM         
    Departman d 
  INNER JOIN StaffsBusiness sb ON d.ID = sb.StaffsPersonelDepartmanID
  INNER JOIN StaffsPersonel sp ON sb.StaffsPersonelID = sp.ID 
  WHERE
    d.Name = @departman
END
```

---

I need a stored procedure function I write below:

```
var staffPersonel = staffContext.GetPersonelInformationWithDepartmanID("Yazılım");

gvPersonel.DataSource = staffPersonel;
gvPersonel.DataBind();
```

GetPersonelInformationWithDepartmanID function I write from SQL (user defined function in ADO.NET Entity Framework) there are 3 alternative (it is silly!!!) but i have 3 joininig table!!!. How can i use if i join 3 table before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, you need a few steps here:

- add your stored procedure `sp_GetDepartmanData` to your Entity Framework model
  (as an aside - it's is **strongly** recommend **NOT** to call your stored procedures `sp_(something)` - use of the `sp_` prefix is reserved for Microsoft-only system stored procedures)
- since your stored procedure is returning a set of data, you will need to create a conceptual entity for it first, before you can use your stored proc; in the Entity Designer, create a new entity and call it some useful name like `DepartmentDataEntityType` or something; add all the fields being returned from the stored procedure to that entity type
- now, you can create your function import in the entity data model - go to the model browser, in the "model.store" section go to your stored procedure, and right-click on "create function import"
- you can now give your function in the object context a name and define what it returns - in this case, pick your newly created entity type (e.g. `DepartmentDataEntityType` from above)
- you're done!

You should now have a function import something like:

```
public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<DepartmentDataEntityType> GetPersonelInformationWithDepartmanID(global::System.String departmentName)
{
    global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter departmentNameParameter;

    departmentNameParameter = new global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("departmentNameParameter", departmentName);

    return base.ExecuteFunction<DepartmentDataEntityType>("sp_GetDepartmanData", departmentNameParameter);
}
```

This function on your object context can now be call to retrieve the data via the stored procedure from your database.

Marc

**Edit:**

If you are getting a mapping error ("Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet") after doing this, it's because the entity you created is not mapped to anything and is only ever used when the function import populates a collection of these entities. You either need to map this entity to a data store somehow or you need to change it to a complex type.

To create a complex type simply open up the EF designer and right-click on an empty area. Go to Add > Complex Type. You should see a new complex type appear in the model browser. Right click it and add scalar properties similar to how you added properties to your entity. Then delete your entity and rename your complex type the same as the entity.

That's all you have to do :)

Comment: Hi Marc. I tried following your instructions, here .. and I can't get it working when I have a POCO setup. If I allow the designer to create my classes, then this works. Do you know how to do this with POCO'S?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: no, sorry, I haven't really done anything with EF4 POCO's, so I cannot really say....

Comment: This works, but I get a persistent error in the error list that says "Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet". What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Comment: I figured out the problem. You cannot create an entity that is not mapped. Instead create a complex type. I will update this answer with the information.

Answer (score 1):

How do you create this "conceptual entity"?
If I create an entity which is not mapped to the I get the following error: "Entity type 'foobar' is not mapped to the database.

Comment: I'm getting this error too... from what I can tell it's a 1.0 bug that they don't intend to fix until 4.0 comes out in March. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=378518&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Bummer :( I'm using VS2010 and i'm still having this issue .. even though that MS Connect says the bug is 'fixed'. WTF :( qq :(

Answer (score 0):

here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cd71317f-407f-4038-9a30-17dd7f529aa3

and here http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/20/entity-framework-40-scalar-and-void-functions/