# Calling SP's in .Net MVC 4 + EF 5

Tags: .net

My question is, can we call SP's from EF as we call using ADO.Net commands. If Yes, can you please post some sample codes.

I have just started working on .Net MVC 4+ EF 5(ORM). But don't have much idea how EF works.
Is EF is better than ADO.Net objects?. I am new to this type of coding. So need some clarification on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Jagadisha

Comment: A quick Google search for "Entity Framework stored procedures" seems to return a lot of helpful information.  As for which framework is better, that's entirely subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your EDMX file for the Model you are creating.  Then right click in the file and click 'Update Model From Database'.  Select the function/SP that you wish to import and click 'Update.'  Then, right click in the same EDMX file, and click 'Add New/Function Import,' and add a 'Method Name' to the 'Function Name' field.

Once you've added your import to the dbcontext, you will now be able to use the dbcontext.MethodName syntax to call the proc as a function.

Here's a great article with the steps and more details...

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/execute-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can.
There is a lot articles about this topic:

[Tutorial 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024331/how-to-use-a-stored-procedure-in-ado-net-entity-framework)

[Other Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7e15e64-5724-44ce-a047-d256424a1e7f/how-to-call-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework)